# How do I detect typo with Boost.program_options?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I use boost.program_options library. Consider this simplified case.

```
po::options_description desc("Usage");
desc.add_options()
("uninstall,u", "uninstall program")
("custom,c", po::wvalue<std::wstring>(), "specify custom action");

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

I want to produce error on such command-line:

```
testprog.exe -u c- action1
```

Note, user made a typo "c-" instead of "-c". But the parser understands this as a single -u option. How do I handle such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to produce error on such command-line:
>
> ```
> testprog.exe -u c- action1
> ```
>
> Note, user made a typo "c-" instead of "-c". But the parser
>   understands this as a single -u option. How do I handle such cases?

Instruct the `program_options` library to accept no positional arguments and you get the desired behavior

code & compile:

```
macmini:stackoverflow samm$ cat po.cc
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    namespace po = boost::program_options;
    po::options_description desc("Usage");
    desc.add_options()
        ("uninstall,u", "uninstall program")
        ("custom,c", po::wvalue<std::wstring>(), "specify custom action")
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::command_line_parser cmd_line( argc, argv );
    cmd_line.options( desc );
    cmd_line.positional( po::positional_options_description() );

    try {
        po::store( cmd_line.run(), vm );

        po::notify(vm);
    } catch ( const std::exception& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
macmini:stackoverflow samm$ g++ po.cc -I /opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_program_options -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib
```

run:

```
macmini:stackoverflow samm$ ./a.out -u c- action1
too many positional options
macmini:stackoverflow samm$ ./a.out -u -c action1
macmini:stackoverflow samm$
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare `argc-1` to the number of arguments found by `program_options`? If it doesn't match, there is a syntax error.

It won't catch all cases but it may catch those important to you.

Comment: I like this answer but it could be better if you provided some sample code

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can do this is to ensure that each argument you require is present, for example by testing the count of each type.

```
if (vm.count("uninstall")) { ... }
if (vm.count("custom")) { ... }
```

You can generate an error if the options you require are not present (i.e. count is 0) or are present (for example `-u` and `-c` cannot be specified would be count of both is `>0`).

Comment: -c option is optional. User may specify a single -u option or both -u and -c options. The problem is if user make the above typo the library treats command line as if there is a single parameter and program may do something unexpected for him or her.

Comment: in this case then you have no choice but to somehow validate the arguments, so if `-u` is provided, check the passed in argument matches what you require before taking action. AFAIK, there is no other way - to account for user error....

Comment: -u option is registered as option without values. So if I try to validate arguments passed in then boost::bad_any_cast exception is thrown.                       std::wstring value = vm["custom"].as<std::wstring>();

Comment: Normally with something like this (esp something that sounds like uninstall), it's always worth double checking with the user ("are you *sure* you want to uninstall?") If that was an error, this allows the users to stop the action. In the case of `custom`, the validation exception should be caught and the appropriate usage message displayed. This is what I mean by validating user input.

Comment: I agree with you that it is worth to prompt user before proceeding. On the other hand, the description of -u and -u + -c actions looks similar and he/she may not spot the difference. Also bad_any_cast exception is _always_ raised for -u option because it is registered as option without values. So I don't see any sense to catch it.